# How do i get an OTP the second time after I've logged out the first time?

Tags: java, android, authentication, one-time-password

After I log in the first time and log out, the next time I log in I don't get an OTP. 
How do I solve this problem?? 
The code works fine if I enter the phone number for the first time. Second time onwards I am not getting OTP number. In order to get the OTP number, I need to restart my phone each time. If I close and reopen the app then it's not helping me too.

**VerifyPhoneActivity**

```
public class VerifyPhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String verificationId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);

        progressBar =findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        String phonenumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phonenumber");
        setVerificationCode(phonenumber);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                if(code.isEmpty() || code.length()< 6){
                    editText.setError("Enter code");
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                verifyCode(code);

            }
        });

    }

    private void verifyCode(String code){
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        SignInWithCredential(credential);
    }

    private void SignInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    private void setVerificationCode(String number){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                number,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
                mCallBack
        );
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code =phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if(code != null){
                editText.setText(code);
                SignInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this facing the same issue in my app

Answer (score 0):

You should read docs if mobile gets registered on firebase it won't send OTP all time, maybe few times.

Once mobile is registered you will get success and then you can verify.

Comment: Not helping... :(